# Jquery sortable not dropping

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-draggable, jquery-droppable

I have a weird issue with jquery sortable and droppable elements.
I want to have a list that is sortable and a list from which I can drag elements to add to that list, I don't want that second list to be sortable or droppable.
I use the following code to make it happen :

```
$(".list_sortable").sortable({
        accept: ".ui-sortable"
});

$(".list_no_drop li").draggable({
        appendTo:'body',
        connectToSortable:'.list_sortable'
});
```

I have no idea why this would not work on my page.

My full code can be seen here : http://jsfiddle.net/9RURx/31/

In Jsfiddle it works just fine, but in my page the elements do not "drop". I can move them but they keep following the mouse after I release the click.

So I thought that I had a problem with  the include of jquery so I downloaded the last version and called it instead but no change.
The complete call of external scritps is following in case there is something I missed :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/jquery-ui.css" />
<link href="/media/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/media/video.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/jqueryMultiSelect/jqueryMultiSelect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/jqueryMultiSelect/jquery.multiselect.filter.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/media/jqueryMultiSelect/jquery.multiselect.filter.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/media/jqueryMultiSelect/jqueryMultiSelect.css"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: use firebug or developer tool and check for any errors?

Comment: Yeah, I checked firebug but no error